# $G = \langle a, b : a^3 = b^2 = (ab)^3 = e \rangle$. Find the order of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

$G$ = $\langle$$a, b : a^3 = b^2 = (ab)^3 = e \rangle$. What is |$G$|.

I don't even know where to begin for this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you certainly have $a,b,e\in G$. Now start multiplying combinations of $a$ and $b$ together to obtain new elements. Use the relations given in the presentation for $G$ to list out all possible combinations. For instance, if we start with $aabbab$ we actually have $aabbab=aaeab=eb=b$.

Comment: Looks like $A_4$.

Comment: You might search for Von Dyck groups.

Comment: The group is isomorphic to $A_4$, see Proposition $4.7$ and the example following it in the text *Presetations of Groups* by Derek Holt.

Comment: @Pratyush Chopra: See https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/fbouyer/presentation_of_group.pdf

Comment: Ah I see - it wasn't me who put the notes online. I think it is a mixture of printed lecture notes and notes taken by a student. There is a mistake right at the beginning. $D_{10}$ is not the unique group of order $10$ - unique nonabelian group perhaps?

Comment: @Pratyush Chopra: If you edit your question in such a way that it looses the on-hold status, I give you a detailed answer (which is not possible at the moment because of the on-hold).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to go here is to bound the number of combinations of $a$ and $b$ as per Dave suggestion. Here is how you should begin, first by definition, any element of $g$ will be written as:

$$a^{n_1}b^{m_1}\dots a^{n_r}b^{m_r} $$
where $n_i$ and $m_i$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$. Now I claim that you can choose $n_i=0,1$ or $2$ and $m_i=0$ or $1$. Do you see why?

Then you need to justify that $ba^2$ can be replaced by $(ab)^2$ and then you should be able to conclude that $G$ is finite (you should even be able to make an explicit list of elements). The hardest part IMHO is to show that the remaining elements are not trivial and different from each other. The best way to do this is probably to find elements in a known group verifying these relations (Gerry Myerson gave a suggestion).